# Check status of the ChannelFactory channel

Tags: c#, channelfactory

in my project I need to check if channell is in faulted state before initialize communication on it but I'm getting a cast exception doing it like this:

```
public class myClass : myInterface
{
private myInterface _service;

public myClass()
  {
    ///service initialization
    //.....///
    this._service = new ChannelFactory<myInterface>(binding, remoteAddress).CreateChannel();
  }

public void login()
  {
       //This is where i get cast exception
       if ((**(ChannelFactory<myInterface>)_service).State** == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            // re-initialize service
            ///....
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try casting `_service` to `ICommunicationObject`

Comment: this worked, thanks!